# JSON formatting

Tags: php, javascript, json

Using the method found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/serialize-form-to-json-with-jquery/1186309#1186309), I am collecting form values and posting them using the following code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://"+document.domain+"/SimplaAdmin/includes/rpc.php",
    data: { data:postdata, method: 'addSite'},
    dataType: "json",
.......
```

Posted data is:

```
data:{
    "textfield": ["",""],
    "dropdown": ["option1","option1"],
    "siteTitle":"this is the site title",
    "siteKey":"",
    "siteurl":"",
    "address1":"",
    "address2":"",
    "address3":"",
    "landline":"",
    "method":"addSite",
    "small-input":"",
    "medium-input":"",
    "large-input":""
}
```

Then I try to get the value `siteTitle` using:

```
$data = $_POST['data'];
$obj=json_decode($data) ;
$title = $obj->{'siteTitle'};
```

But it does not work, where is the flaw in my thinking?

Comment: try json.stringify - Google-ify it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON was escaping the POST. Removed slashes and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is incorrect- You just need `$title = $obj->siteTitle;`

Also, I presume you added `data:` to the start of your JSON string for the purpose of this post? That also shouldn't be there.

Take for example:

```
<?php 

$string = '{"textfield":["",""],"dropdown":["option1","option1"],"siteTitle":"this is the site title","siteKey":"","siteurl":"","address1":"","address2":"","address3":"","landline":"","method":"addSite","small-input":"","medium-input":"","large-input":""}';

$obj = json_decode($string); 

print_r( $obj->siteTitle );

?>
```

Which outputs

`this is the site title`

Comment: This returns null. data: is just what I grab from chrome, to show what is posted, it isn't there.

Comment: Have you tried print_r( $obj ); to see if it's actually decoding the string properly?

Comment: Perhaps try removing `data:` from `data: { data:postdata, method: 'addSite'},` so it looks like this `data: { postdata, method: 'addSite'},`

Comment: yep just did that, it's escaped! ala json post. Did a stripslashes($data) prior to the decode and now it works.

Comment: Nice one. Glad you've got it sorted.

Answer (score -1):

Change `$title = $obj->{'siteTitle'}` to

```
$title = $obj['siteTitle'];
```

Comment: It's not an array though. You need to pass a second argument with `TRUE` if you want an array returned.

Comment: This will not work as by default `json_decode` returns an object. This will result in a Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array error