# Automatically assign POST JSON to a variable based on NAME

Tags: php, json

Using the code found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/serialize-form-to-json-with-jquery/1186309#1186309) I am posting input fields to a php script. The result looks something like this

```
 data:{
"textfield": ["",""],
"dropdown": ["option1","option1"],
"siteTitle":"this is the site title",
"siteKey":"",
"siteurl":"",
"address1":"",
"address2":"",
"address3":"",
"landline":"",
"method":"addSite",
"small-input":"",
"medium-input":"",
"large-input":""
}
```

I am picking off each field using the following.

```
 $data = $_POST['data'];
 $data =stripslashes($data);
 $obj = json_decode($data); 
 $siteTitle = sanitize($obj->siteTitle);
 if (!$siteTitle){echo json_encode(array("msg"=> "Site title missing"));break;}
```

Is there a way in php to automatically step thru each posted `field` and assign it to a variable based on the `name` ?

for those concerned about Déjà vu, [don't be.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7748032/json-formatting)

Comment: You're basically asking for a slightly different version of [`register_globals`](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) which is a rather significant security risk. I'd suggest not going that route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$obj = json_decode($data);
foreach($obj as $key => $val)
{
    $$key = $val;
}
var_dump($method); // 'addSite'
```

Comment: Help me understand the last piece of this code. What would be passed through var_dump?

Comment: I have no idea - 4 years ago and it makes no sense today.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
$array = json_decode($json, true);
extract($array);
```

but let me **STRONGLY** encourage you to **NOT** do this. It's extremely lazy programming, leaves your script open to variable injection attacks, and basically tries to recreate the horribly stupid moronically bad times of PHP in its "register_global defaults to on" days of infamy.

Comment: Yes, this was my thinking also. So really this was an ethics question as much as technical one. But I can't see the vulnerability as I am requesting the variable and sanitizing it as opposed the variable just becoming available.

Comment: Nothing says a malicious user can't fake a post to your form and submit `_SESSION[issuperuser]=1` type thing. Unless you're manually specifying each variable you want to be auto-created in this manner, and just loop over every var submitted, ANYTHING can be injected into your script. This is why register_globals was/is/always will be such a moronic idea.